# SBS 2008 VPN Performance

Tags: vpn

I've configured our SBS 2008 to accept VPN connections (because I can't seem to get our Cisco router's VPN working). I know that the VPN connection is going to be as fast as the connection itself so theoretically if I've got 2Mbit UP/512Kbit DOWN on server side (our office) and client side (my house, same ISP), I'll get a "symmetrical" 512Kbit connection.

Browsing shared folders located on the server shouldn't even be a problem if that's the case but lately, Explorer has been freezing for about 4-5 seconds before stuff loads up in the Explorer window (while browsing Shared Folders).

Is there any way I can test for my real connection speed? or maybe there's a setting in SBS 2008 I've missed (I have searched online but couldn't find anything related to this).

Answer (score 0):

There are speed test software packs around - you could at least run a flash based one from both sides. That said, symmetrical 512 is theoretical - dont forget that anything the server does limits his side... there are tons of reasons why connections get partially stuck, from small packet loss to downloads happeningin the background.

Comment: Yes that is understandable especially during office hours, but I am talking about accessing the VPN and file shares on 2AM on a Sunday trying to copy/paste a patch to our program. So judging by your reply, there wouldn't be any setting at all to "boost" SBS 2008's VPN performance? Would a router based VPN be any better such as Cisco's IPSec?

Comment: No, it is likely you hunt ghosts here - as in: the reason is not related to SBS at all. The theoreitcla limit can be quite theoretical depending on the quality of the providers on both ends.

Comment: IF you want to go hardware, Mikrotik is a lot more reasonable price wise than Cisco.

Comment: Well, I already have a Cisco router but for some reason the IPSec won't work (I'm doing it wrong?). Meh, I'll just suck it up and find out why this thing's so slow. - MODS please close this threat already thanks